# Python JSON to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

i have json in format

```
   {
   "projects":[
      {
         "author":{
            "id":163,
            "name":"MyApp",
            "easy_external_id":null
         },
         "sum_time_entries":0,
         "sum_estimated_hours":29,
         "currency":"EUR",
         "custom_fields":[
            {
               "id":42,
               "name":"System",
               "internal_name":null,
               "field_format":"string",
               "value":null
            },
            {
               "id":40,
               "name":"Short describe",
               "internal_name":null,
               "field_format":"string",
               "value":""
            }
         ]
      }
   ]"total_count":1772,
   "offset":0,
   "limit":1
}
```

And I don't know how to convert this Json "completely" to a dataframe. Respectively, I just want what's in `projects`. But when I do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['projects'])
```

Although I only get the dataframe from projects, in some columns (for example: `author` or `custom_fields`) the format will still remain undecomposed and I would like to decompose it in these columns as well.
can anyone advise?

I expect:

| author.id | author.name | author.easy_external_id | sum_time_entries | currency | custom_fields.id | custom_fields.name | etc.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 163 | MyApp | null | 0 | EUR | 42 | System | ... |

Comment: Can you make an example of how you expect the df to be?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['projects'])
```

See documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

Comment: When I do: df = pd.json_normalize(data['projects']) the author will decompose right(author.name, author.id etc..) for me, but custom_fields will remain undecomposed

Comment: The answer is missing because there's an embedded field wich is custom_fields. I've added updates to the code and I believe this will work because you can have N field in the custon_fields.  ` df = pd.json_normalize(a['projects'])
df_1 = df['custom_fields'].apply(pd.Series)
counter = 0
for col in df_1.columns:
    res = pd.json_normalize(df_1[col])
    res.columns = ['custom_fields_{}'.format(col_name+str(counter)) for col_name in res.columns]
    counter= counter +1
    df = pd.concat([df,res],axis=1)
df = df.drop(["custom_fields"],axis=1)
df`   @Cesc

Comment: @alphaBetaGamma Would it please show more legible, or through some link? Thank you.

Comment: `df = pd.json_normalize(a['projects'])  #newligne
df_1 = df['custom_fields'].apply(pd.Series)  #newligne
counter = 0 for col in df_1.columns:  #newligne
 res = pd.json_normalize(df_1[col]) #newligne
 res.columns = ['custom_fields_{}'.format(col_name+str(counter)) for col_name in res.columns] #newligne
 counter = counter + 1 #newligne
  df = pd.concat([df,res],axis=1) #newligne
df = df.drop(["custom_fields"],axis=1)  /n
df `

Comment: Apologies but the comments doesn't support newlines  so I added comment to explain that. 
`df = pd.json_normalize(a['projects'])  #newline
df_1 = df['custom_fields'].apply(pd.Series)  #newline
counter = 0 #newline
for col in df_1.columns:  #newline 
 /// inside loop /////
 res = pd.json_normalize(df_1[col]) #newline
 res.columns = ['custom_fields_{}'.format(col_name+str(counter)) for col_name in res.columns] #newline
 counter = counter + 1 #newligne
  df = pd.concat([df,res],axis=1) #newline
   ///////endloopp////

df = df.drop(["custom_fields"],axis=1) #newline
df `  @Cesc

Answer (score 0):

I tried here and it works... I think the problem is in your JSON file. Try doing:

```
data = {'projects': [{'author': {'id': 163,
    'name': 'MyApp',
    'easy_external_id': None},
   'sum_time_entries': 0,
   'sum_estimated_hours': 29,
   'currency': 'EUR',
   'custom_fields': [{'id': 42,
     'name': 'System',
     'internal_name': None,
     'field_format': 'string',
     'value': None},
    {'id': 40,
     'name': 'Short describe',
     'internal_name': None,
     'field_format': 'string',
     'value': ''}]}],
 'total_count': 1772,
 'offset': 0,
 'limit': 1}
```

Comment: Not with me. When I do: `df = pd.json_normalize(data['projects'])` the `author` will decompose right(author.name, author.id etc..) for me, but `custom_fields` will remain undecomposed.